# Show and hide elements based on wether there is any overflow-x (horizontal scrolling) in Angular 8

Tags: html, css, angular, scroll, overflow

I have an angular application. In the menubar I'm displaying the path of the current routerLink. Which in some parts of the application can get pretty wide. So wide that it is creating a horizontal scrolling. What I would like to do is to hide that path the second the scrolling appears and show another element instead (this will happen on smaller screens). Not sure if I am supposed to do this in pure css och programmatically in the ts file.

So I basically want to remove 'someclass' when there is overflow-x and instead show 'whenthereisoverflow'. I want to move the link path to a new toolbar when there is overflow.

I do not want to use media queries or similair solutions beacuse the width of the path can vary depending on where you are in the application.

```
<mat-toolbar>
 <div class="someclass">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a [routerLink]="link.url">
                {{ link.url }}
            </a>
        </li> 
    </ul>
  </div>

<div>Some other content</div>
 </mat-toolbar>


<mat-toolbar class="whenthereisoverflow">
 <div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a [routerLink]="link.url">
                {{ link.url }}
            </a>
        </li> 
    </ul>
  </div
 </mat-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><p>skdjfhksjdfhksjd fhksdjfhksdjfh ksjdhfksjdfhskdjfhs skdjfhsdfk skdjfhksjdfhksjd fhksdjfhksdjfh ksjdhfksjdfhskdjfhs skdjfhsdfk</p></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Not really what I'm looking for tho. In your example I would saythat <p> needs to be removed if overflow appears. Not minimized.

Comment: @indd, Give an example of code or text that should be in place of the link and that you would like to shorten

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get this done by checking whether the content of the `div` is overflowing. Use the following snippet to do that.

> comp-1.component.html

```
<mat-toolbar>
    <div id="divToCheck">
        <div id="divToModify">
            <!--content-->
        </div>
    </div>
</mat-toolbar>
```

> comp-1.component.ts

```
checkOverflowing() {
    const element = document.getElementById('divToCheck');

    const curOverflow = element.style.overflow;

    if (!curOverflow || curOverflow === 'visible') {
      element.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    }

    const isOverflowing = element.clientWidth < element.scrollWidth || element.clientHeight < element.scrollHeight;

    element.style.overflow = curOverflow;

    if (isOverflowing) {
      document.getElementById('divToModify').classList.add('someclass');
    } else {
      document.getElementById('divToModify').classList.add('whenthereisoverflow');
    }

  }
```

this will check whether `divToCheck` is overflowing and add the relevant class to `divToModify` as you wish.

Hope this helps!

Good luck!!

Comment: it works fine in the ide (webstorm). maybe there is a problem with rendering it on stackblitz

Comment: could you show your css file as well? maybe i've done something wrong in there because it is not working in my ide (vsc) either

Comment: well, nothing much in the css file other than changing the background color. and that's strange! usually it's not ide dependent because this is a simple script. if possible share the githum repo with the code, so i can check it with the exact codebase